# Are points $x\in (-1,1)$ only interior points or also limit points in $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual topology?

Tags: general-topology

[Here](https://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~gerald/ftp/book-schroe/schroe.pdf) on page 4 one writes: "A point $x$ is called a limit point of U if $(B_r(x)\setminus \{x\})\cap U\neq \emptyset $ for every ball around $x$." (The definition of a ball around $x$ and of an interior point can be found in the mentioned link.)

Then the following example is mentioned:
"Consider $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual metric and let $U = (−1, 1)$. Then every point $x\in U$ is an interior point of $U$. The points ±1 are limit points of U."

However, it seems to me that according to the above definition all points $x\in \{-1,1\}\cup (-1,1)=[-1,1]$ are limit points of $U$, because the intersection of any ball around these $x$ with $U$ is a non-empty set. What is what I do not see?

Comment: Yes, all points of $U = (-1,1)$ are limit points of $U$. The book is just saying that $1$ and $-1$ are also limit points (even though they don't belong to $U$).

Comment: An interior point x  of U is also a limit point of U, whenever every deleted neighborhood of x contains infinitely many points from U.

Comment: @TonyK Ok, but the formulation in the book should be more made more clear, don't you think? I find it confusing.